# F5 & F8 has expected result, but button press skipping code

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, form-control

The code takes around 20 seconds to run when pressing F5 and the result is correct.  When the button is pressed it takes about 2 seconds and the result is incorrect.

Working - The code starts by unprotected the sheet and performs a vlookup from 1 sheet to another and inserts new rows if new data is found.

Not Working - The next part should autofill cells in column B to the end of the new row range and add N/A to each cell in the new row up to the end of column range.

At the end of the code it protects the sheet and gives a msgbox to confirm complete (this is also working).

```
Sub ChkNewAccs()

 Dim wb As Workbook, wsToday As Worksheet, wsBalances As Worksheet
 Dim lastRow As Long, r As Long, arr, v
 Dim newrow As Long
 Dim Rng As Range
 Dim FillRng As Range
  
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
 Worksheets("Balances2").Protect Contents:=False
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsToday = wb.Worksheets("Todays Bals")
    Set wsBalances = wb.Worksheets("Balances2")
    
    lastRow = wsToday.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = wsToday.Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Value
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        v = arr(r, 1)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
           
            If IsError(Application.Match(v, wsBalances.Columns(1), 0)) Then
                With wsBalances
                    newrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Cells(newrow, 1).EntireRow.Insert
                End With
                wsBalances.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = v
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

 Call AddNANewAccs

End Sub
```

```
Sub AddNANewAccs()

 Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
 Dim Rng As Range
 Dim WholeRng As Range
 Dim Cell As Range
    
    With Worksheets("Balances2")
        Set Rng = .Cells
        
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = Worksheets("Balances2").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            
        Set WholeRng = .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
        
        For Each Cell In WholeRng
            Cell.Value = IIf(IsEmpty(Cell), "N/A", Cell.Value)
        Next
            
    End With
    
 Worksheets("Balances2").Protect Contents:=True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
 MsgBox "Completed"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing many parent sheet references to your range and cell objects.  Provide those sheet references to all your range and cells objects and it will work properly.

Comment: Sorry @ScottCraner - I'm quite new to VBA - please can you elaborate on what I need to change?

Comment: Any where you have `Cells()` or `Range()` that does not have the worksheet in front ie:`Worksheets("Balances2").Cells(...)` you need to add the parent worksheet.  when you press the button the wrong worksheet is active and why you are getting incorrect returns.